# Create manual mock for @material-ui withStyles in React with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs, material-ui

I am trying to create manual mocks for the `@material-ui/core/styles` module, which exports the HOC called `withStyles`.

Using the inline mock with `jest.mock` works perfectly, but when I try to move this logic into sharable `__mocks__` folder, it does not work anymore.

I removed from the file being tested all the unecessary code, just keeping the two lines creating the issues:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

console.log('loaded styles:', withStyles);

export default 'hello';
```

And the test simplified as well, just to see if the mock is working, is the following:

```
import test from '../test';
console.log(test);
```

What I have tried is to create a `__mocks__` folder in the root of the project, where I have the `node_modules` folder.

There I created a first folder called `@material-ui` and inside it another folder called `core`. 
Inside this folder I have a file called `styles.js` with the following code:

```
export const withStyles = 'hello world';
```

So the structure looks like:

```
- __mocks__
  - @material-ui
    - core
      - styles.js
- node_modules
```

This is the code which works, with the mock defined inside the same testing file:

```
jest.mock('@material-ui/core/styles', () => ({
  withStyles: () => Component => props => (
    <Component
      classes=""
      {...props}
    />
  ),
}));
```

What is happening with the `__mocks__` folder is that, if I do not call any

```
jest.mock('@material-ui/core/styles');
```

inside my test file, it uses the real `withStyles`, so the real module.
No mock at all is being used.

If I use the:

```
jest.mock('@material-ui/core/styles');
```

It uses an automatic mock autogenerated by jest (or it looks so), skipping the one I define above.

Just a note about packages, I used `CRA` for bootstrapping the app and the `jest` version I currently have is the 20, with the `react-scripts` version 1.0.17

Thanks to you all for you the help!

Comment: I found the PERFECT way to manual mock makeStyles in (`__mocks__/@material-ui/core/styles.js`) by using the same original makeStyles bound with a theme created on the go. That solved all problems from `undefined theme`, Test Coverage, uncovered test on passed `props` inside `makeStyles` function property. If you still want this I'll take a time to answer it, because it also handle `jest.spyOn(React, 'useContext').mockImplementation(() => {})` which crashes some `useStyles` that also make use of `React.useContext` internally.

Comment: It's similar to `withStyles`, but `makeStyles` is more appropriate for Hook, which is what I use. But the same logic would apply.

Comment: Also, you should not use `jest.mock('@material-ui/core/styles');` in manual mock. In Manual Mock, you must just return any content that you want in place of `styles`. For example, you can just import all Styles, prepare a `withStyles` function and return `{ ....Styles. withStyles }` to replace just the `withStyles`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should use manual mocking in `__mocks__/@material-ui/core/styles.js`:

```
// Grab the original exports
import * as Styles from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const mockWithStyles = () => {
  console.log('withStyles being mocked'); // this shows that it works
  /**
   * Note: if you want to mock this return value to be
   * different within a test suite then use
   * the pattern defined here:
   * https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks
   */

  return () => {}; // your mock function (adjust as needed)
  // you can also return the same implementation on certain conditions
  // return Styles.makeStyles; 
};

module.exports = { ...Styles, withStyles: mockWithStyles };
```

Here is how I manual mock `makeStyles`:

```
// Grab the original exports
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import * as Styles from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import createMuiTheme from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
import options from '../../../src/themes/options';

const mockMakeStyles = func => {
  /**
   * Note: if you want to mock this return value to be
   * different within a test suite then use
   * the pattern defined here:
   * https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks
   */

  /**
   * Work around because Shallow rendering does not
   * Hook context and some other hook features.
   * `makeStyles` accept a function as argument (func)
   * and that function accept a theme as argument
   * so we can take that same function, passing it as
   * parameter to the original makeStyles and
   * binding it with our custom theme
   */
  const theme = createMuiTheme(options);
  return Styles.makeStyles(func.bind(null, theme));
};

module.exports = { ...Styles, makeStyles: mockMakeStyles };
```

And `makeStyles` result uses `React.useContext`, so we have to avoid mocking `useContext` for `makeStyles`. Either use `mockImplementationOnce` if you use `React.useContext(...)` first in you component, or just filter it out in your test code as:

```
jest.spyOn(React, 'useContext').mockImplementation(context => {
  console.log(context);
  // only stub the response if
  if (context.displayName === 'MyAppContext') {
    return {
      auth: {},
      lang: 'en',
      snackbar: () => {},
    };
  }

  const ActualReact = jest.requireActual('react');
  return ActualReact.useContext(context);
});
```

And on your `createContext()` call, probably in a `store.js`, add a `displayName` (standard), or any other custom property to Identify your context:

```
const store = React.createContext(initialState);
store.displayName = 'MyAppContext';
```

The `makeStyles` context displayName will appear as `StylesContext` and `ThemeContext` and their implementation will remain untouched to avoid error.

This fixed all kind of mocking problem with `makeStyles`. But I haven't use `withStyles` to know its structure deeply, but similar logic should be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I created the file `src/__mocks__/@material-ui/core/styles.jsx` in my project and inside I put:

```
import * as Styles from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import React from 'react';

const withStyles = () => Component => props => <Component classes={{}} {...props} />;

module.exports = { ...Styles, withStyles };
```